# Cannot start Postgres daemon after installing with Yum

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, yum, postgresql, apt-get

I was trying to install Postgres 9.1.4 on Fedora 17 using Yum. If I do:

```
sudo yum install postgres-libs
sudo yum install postgres
sudo yum install postgis
```

All the installs appear to complete successfully (i.e., no errors), but I cannot start the Postgres daemon using:

```
service postgresql initdb
```

Like the official Postgres download guide says to do (http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/). The error says `Unknown operation initdb`.

RPM tells me that it installed psql to `/usr/bin/`, which I confirmed. It turns out that only a few components installed correctly (`psql`, `pg_dump`, `pg_configure`, and a few others), but most are missing (e.g., `pg_ctl` and `postgres`).

I've tried several different configurations and had several of my coworkers (with more linux experience than me) look at it, but so far nothing has worked.
Two of them have also run into similar issues installing Postgres using apt-get on Ubuntu, which makes me think the rpm isn't doing its job. It seems the only solution to build it from source, which is more robust anyway, but of course it takes longer.

I'm wondering, though, if anyone else has run into this issue and/or has successfully installed Postgres on either Fedora or Ubuntu using a package manager like yum or apt-get? Is the rpm broken?

Comment: Don't forget to give credit where credit is due and upvote the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `service postgresql initdb` command does not work because now `service` just calls systemd, and all of these random helper functions are gone. As documented [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Sysadmin.html), you now need to do:

```
sudo postgresql-setup initdb
```

to accomplish the same thing.

The rest of your mystery is also simple: you're missing the `postgresql-server` package.

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server
```

And then you'll have `/usr/bin/pg_ctl` and `/usr/bin/postgres`. Running `yum search postgres` is a helpful way to look for clues, but you can also do `sudo yum install /usr/bin/pg_ctl` or similar, and yum will figure out what package provides the missing file.

Comment: Thanks! I think that would do the trick, since Yum did not install the `postgresql-server` package automatically. I ended up giving Fedora the boot and installing Arch anyway, and suddenly life got a lot better. Pacman handles everything nicely with `sudo pacman -S postgres`.